# Enterprise Gateway connection issues - The CORP\user does not have permission to call the Discover method

Tags: powerbi, ssas, gateway

I have a Power BI Report with a live connection to an Analysis Service Cube. When publishing the report, I need to use a gateway. The goal is the share the report with colleagues.

I keep getting the error message: "The CORP\user does not have permission to call the Discover method."
I'm not the admin of the cube and won't receive admin rights. Is there a certain right I can request? Or another way to make this work with an enterprise gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account being used for the Gateway connection requires the "Administrator" permissions granted within the Role to be able to call the discovery method.