User doesn't have permission to call the Discover method
Using Microsoft.AnalysisServices package and Connecting to Power BI account. This the code

using Server = Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server;


class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling Function");
        await ConnectPowerBIAccount();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task ConnectPowerBIAccount()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease, connect with your Power BI account");

        //Source connection for connecting to Power BI
        string sourceConnection = $"powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg";

        string sourceConnectString = $"DataSource={sourceConnection};";

        Server sourceServer = new Server();
        sourceServer.Connect(sourceConnectString);

        Console.WriteLine("Connected Successfully");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}

After logging into Power BI account, Facing this error.

It was working earlier but when my trail license expired, Admin assigned me Premium per user and from that time, facing this issue. Able to connect with Power BI account of different tenant successfully.
I guess I'm missing some admin permission. Could anyone please help me how can I resolve this issue?

Can you paste the full code?

@Rukmini, there is no issue with code as i was able to connect using powerbi account of different tenant. I check the stackoverflow ticket and shared with my IT team. But is there any doc that i can share with my it team so they can follow and provide me the permission? Thank you

To repro and check in my environment I wanted to see the full code

And check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62594810/enterprise-gateway-connection-issues-the-corp-user-does-not-have-permission-to

@Rukmini, Thanks for your reply. Updated the qns with full code we use to connect to Power BI account. Please look into this. I already went through the stackoverflow ticket you shared yesterday, but looking for doc I can share with Adminstrator that he can follow to assign me that permission.

Could you please look into the code and let me know how can i resolve the issue. Thanks for the help :)

Is the user you are trying to connect is added as admin to the workspace? Check
this and by adding user as admin to the workspace I am able to connect successfully

Or try to assign Fabric administrator role to the user and check

Thanks @Rukmini, will try that and keep you updated. It was working fine with my trail account but facing this issue only when I got myself assigned PPU license. The user is added as admin to workspace.

Sure let me know if it works

Can you try with the URL by passing the workspace name string sourceConnection = $"powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/WorkSpaceName";

Okay, trying ..

@Rukmini, Thanks a lot for you effort and it worked. when I changed the URL and added my WorkspaceName at last, able to connect successfully. But the issue is, I need to connect to 25 workspaces. Earlier there is only login to connect, but with this approach need to login 25 times to connect to 25 workspaces. Checking on this.

I'm still waiting for my IT team to get back to me for assigning fabric administrator role to the user and check

Can I post it as an answer?

Yes, Sure, Thanks a lot :) Will try to assign Fabric administrator role and try with the Old URL, as I don't want to login 25 times to connect to 25 workspaces.

Or you can make use of access token to connect to myorg https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-access-power-bi-rest-apis-programmatically/

Or you can try to pass all your workspace names and connect it in one code like this

thanks a lot @Rukmini, will follow this approach and it will be perfect for my scenario

Which approach passing workspace names?

Yes, I will follow this approach for now i.e passing workspaces

Sure will post it as an answer now


Note that: According to this MsDoc, you need to pass workspace name to connect to PowerBI.

Hence to resolve the issue, you must pass workspace name to the connection string powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/WorkSpaceName
using Server = Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling Function");
        await ConnectPowerBIAccount();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task ConnectPowerBIAccount()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlease, connect with your Power BI account");

        //Source connection for connecting to Power BI
        string sourceConnection = $"powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/WorkSpaceName";

        string sourceConnectString = $"DataSource={sourceConnection};";

        Server sourceServer = new Server();
        sourceServer.Connect(sourceConnectString);

        Console.WriteLine("Connected Successfully");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}


As you have multiple workspaces to connect, you can pass workspace names and loop it like below:
class Program  
{  
static async Task Main(string[] args)  
{  
Console.WriteLine("Calling Function");  
var workspaces = new List<string> { "testruk", "testruk1" };  //Pass your workspace names

await ConnectPowerBIAccount(workspaces);  
Console.ReadLine();  
}

static async Task ConnectPowerBIAccount(List<string> workspaces)  
{  
Console.WriteLine("\nPlease, connect with your Power BI account");

string sourceConnection = $"powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg";

foreach (var workspace in workspaces)  
{  
string sourceConnectString = $"DataSource={sourceConnection}/{workspace};";

Server sourceServer = new Server();  
try  
{  
sourceServer.Connect(sourceConnectString);  
Console.WriteLine($"Connected Successfully to {workspace}");  
}  
catch (Exception ex)  
{  
Console.WriteLine($"Failed to connect to {workspace}: {ex.Message}");  
}  
finally  
{  
sourceServer.Disconnect();  
}  
  
Thread.Sleep(1000);  
}  
}  
}


If you want to connect to powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg, then generate access token and refer this MsDoc and blog by Aveek Das
